# vector-related segmentation fault

Tags: c++, random, vector, segmentation-fault

```
void offer_help();
bool play_one_game();

int main() {

    offer_help();

    play_one_game();

}


void offer_help() {

    int help_response;

    cout << "Need help? (0/1) ";
    cin >> help_response;
    if (help_response == 1)
    cout << "I will generate a pattern of 4 numbers, each in the range 0 through 9.\n Each guess that you enter will be a line containing 4 integers,\n separated by spaces, such as:\n\t 2 4 7 1\n FOr each guess, I will echo back a lost consisting of\n 0's and 1's, with a 1 in a given position meaning that\n  you guessed the number, and a zero meaning that you didn't.\n For example, if the actual solution was 2 3 6 1, I'll respond\n\t 1 0 0 1\n See how many guesses it takes you to get the solution!\n\n If you want to give up, type a negative number for one of\n your guesses, and we'll tell you what the pattern was.\n\n";

}

bool play_one_game() {

    srand(time(0)); //needed to start randint

    vector<int> solution; //vector of 4 randomly generated
                 //solutions
    vector<int> guess; //vector containing user guesses.
    vector<int> result;

    int guess_input;

    for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i)
    solution[i] = randint(10);

    int trial_number = 0; //int that shows what guess the user is on

    while (play_one_game() == true) {    
    //ask user for inputs.
        cout << "Guess #" << ++trial_number << "? ";
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.size(); ++i){
            cin >> guess_input;
            guess.push_back(guess_input);
        }

        //outputs error if user inputs a letter.
    if (!cin) {
        cerr << "Bad input data! Feed me numbers!\n";
        return 43;
    }
    if (cin < 0){
        cout << "Too bad! Solution was " << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        cout << (result[i]);
    }

    //determines if user correctly guessed any of the
    //numbers and tells the user which is correct.
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        if (guess[i]==solution[i])
        cout << 1 << " ";
        else if (guess[i]!=solution[i])
        cout << 0 << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // playagain();
    cout << endl << "Play again (0/1)? ";
    int replay;
    cin >> replay;
    if (replay == 0) {
        play_one_game() == false;
        return 5;
    }
    else if (replay == 1)
        play_one_game() == true;
    else {
        cerr << "wat?\n";
        return 10;    
    }
    }
}
```

This is designed to allow a player to guess a pattern of random numbers.

No idea why I am getting a segmentation fault. The program is supposed to call the offer_help function, then the  play_one_game function within main function. Then it should ask the player whether he wants to play again. If no, then bool play_one_game should be set to false and it should exit.

This is related to the play_one_game bool function.

Comment: Check the bounds -- you're iterating up to `result.size()`, but accessing `guess[i]` and `solution[i]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a segmentation fault, because you end up in an endless recursion in the following line:

```
while (play_one_game() == true) {
```

`play_one_game` will call `play_one_game` in this line, and this will call `play_one_game` in the same line again. This will result in a stack overflow at last.

Better use some `bool keepPlaying;` and `while(keepPlaying)` instead.

**EDIT**: Well, this is a little bit more than a simple answer, but I like games, so... have a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

bool play_one_game();

void offer_help() {
    int help_response;
    std::cout << "Need help? (0/1) ";
    std::cin >> help_response;
    if (help_response == 1)
        std::cout << "I will generate a pattern of 4 numbers, each in the range 0 through 9.\n"
            "Each guess that you enter will be a line containing 4 integers,\n"
            "separated by spaces, such as:\n"
            "\t 2 4 7 1\n"
            "For each guess, I will echo back a lost consisting of\n"
            "0's and 1's, with a 1 in a given position meaning that\n"
            "you guessed the number, and a zero meaning that you didn't.\n"
            "For example, if the actual solution was 2 3 6 1, I'll respond\n"
            "\t 1 0 0 1\n"
            "See how many guesses it takes you to get the solution!\n\n"
            "If you want to give up, type a negative number for one of\n"
            "your guesses, and we'll tell you what the pattern was.\n\n";
}

int main() {
    offer_help();
    srand(time(0)); // Initialize random numbers with current time as seed
    while(play_one_game()); // if play_one_game returns true, play again
}

bool play_one_game() {
    std::vector<int> solution(4); // Four solutions for our guessing game
    std::vector<int> guess;          // User guesses

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i)
        solution[i] = rand() % 10;

    int trial_number = 0; //int that shows what guess the user is on
    bool keepPlaying = true;
    while(keepPlaying){
        std::cout << "Guess #" << ++trial_number << "? ";

        guess.clear(); // Clear old guesses
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i){
            int guess_input;
            //outputs error if user inputs a letter.
            if (!(std::cin >> guess_input)) {
                std::cerr << "Bad input data! Feed me numbers!\n";
                std::cerr << "Try again!" << std::endl;
                std::cin.clear(); // Clear flags
                continue;
            }
            if (guess_input < 0){
                std::cout << "Too bad! Solution was " << std::endl;
                for(unsigned i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++)
                    std::cout << (solution[i]);
                keepPlaying = false;
                break;
            }else
                guess.push_back(guess_input);
        }
        if(!keepPlaying)
            break;
        if(solution.size() != guess.size()){
            std::cerr << "Wrong number of guesses, try again!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        //determines if user correctly guessed any of the
        //numbers and tells the user which is correct.
        bool correct = true;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++) {
            if (guess[i] == solution[i])
                std::cout << 1 << " ";
            else{
                correct = false;
                std::cout << 0 << " ";
            }
        }
        if(correct){
            std::cout << "Congratulations - you won!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    int replay = -1;
    do{
        // Ask user for input until input is 0 or 1
        std::cout << std::endl << "Play again (0/1)? ";
        std::cin >> replay;
    }
    while(replay != 0 && replay != 1);
    return static_cast<bool>(replay); // return user replay answer (false/true)
}
```

[Try to keep your code as simple as possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Welcome to SO. <sub>And don't expect future answers to be that excessive.</sub>

Comment: Yup! Stack Overflow. There are also calls like `play_one_game() == false`.

Answer (score 3):

You're never inserting anything into your solution vector.  You just declare the vector, and then say:

```
for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i)
  solution[i] = randint(10);
```

...which won't do anything since at this point `solution.size() == 0`.  Later, when you iterate over your result vector, you end up accessing invalid elements in your empty solution vector.  You also can't assume that the result vector and solution vector are the same size.